# google test framework best practice to fail a test from TestEventListener

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have TestEventListener that fails a test if it take more than some limit. I have the check in the OnTestEnd where I can check `test_info.result()->elapsed_time()` and I trigger the error with `GTEST_FAIL`.

```
void TimeMonitor::OnTestEnd(const ::testing::TestInfo& test_info)
{
  ...

  GTEST_FAIL()
    << "This test took "
    << test_info.result()->elapsed_time() << " ms "
    << "instead the expected " << expected << " ms.";
}
```

This works with one very annoying exception - the error report code line points to the place where `GTEST_FAIL()` is. I know that this code is correct, I would like to be pointed out to the head of the test that failed instead.

How I can change the code to print the test head location?

Comment: You can use `test_info.test_case_name()` and `test_info.name()`. Is that enough - or you need more info in your printouts?

Comment: The test info is printed anyways. I would like go to error feature to works, as it does for other cases - I need file and line number for that